# What does the author mean in his proof "It follows by induction hypothesis" in theorem 2.3 in the given article below..

Tags: graph-theory

http://www.discuss.wmie.uz.zgora.pl/php/discuss3.php?ip=&url=pdf&nIdA=23384&nIdSesji=-1
What does the author mean in his proof "It follows by induction hypothesis" in theorem 2.3 in the given article below..

Comment: Could you edit to include the actual theorem and proof? We don't like to have to click links to find the problem.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/seq_induction/proof_by_induction/v/proof-by-induction   ---- Here is a walkthrough of proofs by induction by Khan Academy. Induction is a certain type of proof that mathematicians use to prove things.

Answer (score 3):

"By induction on $p$" means a style of proof where you show that for each $p$, if the theorem is true for all trees of size *less than* $p$, then it must be true for trees of size $p$ also.  Then you show that it is true for the smallest trees, of size 1 or 2 (which is easy), and it follows that it is true for all trees of every size.

The "induction hypothesis" is the hypothesis that the statement is true for all trees of size less than $p$.  The proof says this explicitly: “Assume the result is true for every tree of order $p-1$, where $p\ge 3$.” (Trees of sizes 1 and 2 are handled separately.) This is the induction hypothesis.